# Operation in the notation for group homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

> A group homomorphism $\varphi$ from the additive group of real numbers to the multiplicative group of non-zero real mumbers...

Could this be written as $$\varphi :\, (\mathbb{R},+)\to (\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},\cdot )?$$

I'm not sure, because I only encountered the following notation:
$$\varphi :\, \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$$
where they specify the operations on the groups elsewhere.

Comment: Well, it essentially depends on whether the context is ambiguous or not/

Comment: @Bernard So, the 'first' notation in my question is OK? Or how could it be ambiguous?

Comment: Formally, a group is an ordered pair, so the first notation is the "correct" one. But it's annoying to write it like this every time, so when it is clear what the operation is we can just write the set. After all, $\mathbb{R}$ is a group with respect to addition and isn't a group with respect to multiplication, while $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is a group with respect to multiplication and isn't a group with respect to addition. So here it is clear what the operations should be.

Comment: Yes. To make the 2nd less ambiguous – and shorter, you may denote $\Bbb R^\times$ in the place of $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more clear to write as $$\varphi :\, (\mathbb{R},+)\to (\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\},\times).$$
or simply you can write:
$$\varphi :\, (\mathbb{R},+)\to \mathbb{R}^\times.$$ as @Bernard commented.